# Oracle SQL Find and Replace

Tags: sql, oracle

I have lots of rows in a table with an incorrect barcode hidden amongst the strings.

I need to do an update on these to replace anything with fd>; hidden amongst the string to fd>;1.

But this one row could have something like

^XA^XFB:trgt001.zpl^FS^FN2^FDLondon Oxford ^FS^FN4^FD^FS^FN6^FDLONDON^FS^FN8^FDW1C 1DN^FS^FN100^FD>;110032730214^FS^FN1^FDSH

So i'm basically only inserting an additional 1 into the string wherever there's an FD>;

Is this possible please?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: All I could think to try was set data like '%FD>;1% WHERE DATA LIKE '%FD>;%' but that didn't work.

Comment: Any luck yet, with any of the answers?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - found an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE t
SET T.COLUMN = REPLACE(T.COLUMN, 'FD>;', 'FD>;1')
```

Comment: Please remember to include a `where` clause along the lines of `WHERE T.COLUMN LIKE '%FD>;%'`... I had a table with ~1M rows in it where it was taking about a minute per replace. Once I added the where clause, it ran 100x faster (because most rows it had been wasting time doing essentially nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [REPLACE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) function.

```
update YourTable t
set
  t.Barcode = replace(t.Barcode, 'FD>;', 'FD>;1')
```

Note that this function (like string in general) is case sensitive, so it will replace `'FD>;'` but not `'fd>;'`. If you want to do that too, you can make multiple replaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEXP_REPLACE to do a case-insensitive replace too (strings below have different case combinations of 'FD;>':

```
with data as
( select '^XA^XFB:trgt001.zpl^FS^FN2^FDLondon Oxford ^FS^FN4^FD^FS^FN6^FDLONDON^FS^FN8^FDW1C 1DN^FS^FN100^FD>;110032730214^FS^FN1^FDSH' string from dual
  union
  select '^XA^XFB:trgt001.zpl^FS^FN2^FDLondon Oxford ^FS^FN4^FD^FS^FN6^FDLONDON^FS^FN8^FDW1C 1DN^FS^FN100^fD>;110032730214^FS^FN1^FDSH' string from dual
  union
  select '^XA^XFB:trgt001.zpl^FS^FN2^FDLondon Oxford ^FS^FN4^FD^FS^FN6^FDLONDON^FS^FN8^FDW1C 1DN^FS^FN100^fd>;110032730214^FS^FN1^FDSH' string from dual
  union
  select '^XA^XFB:trgt001.zpl^FS^FN2^FDLondon Oxford ^FS^FN4^FD^FS^FN6^FDLONDON^FS^FN8^FDW1C 1DN^FS^FN100^Fd>;110032730214^FS^FN1^FDSH' string from dual
) 
select regexp_replace(string, 'FD>;', 'FD>;1', 1, 0, 'i') from data;
```